# How to determine if is sandboxing enabled or not

Tags: macos, appkit, entitlements

How to check if sandboxing is enabled or not at OSX app runtime?

I need it for some assert tests for my library that can be run in different environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This might help](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH2-SW2)

> 1. In Finder, look at the contents of the ~/Library/Containers/ folder.
>
>    If the Quick Start app is sandboxed, there is now a container folder
>      named after your app. The name includes the company identifier for the
>      project, so the complete folder name would be, for example,
>      com.yourcompany.AppSandboxQuickStart.
>
>    The system creates an app’s container folder, for a given user, the
>      first time the user runs the app.
> 2. In Activity Monitor, check that the system recognizes the app as
>      sandboxed.
>
>    - Launch Activity Monitor (available in /Applications/Utilities).
>    - In Activity Monitor, choose View > Columns. Ensure that the Sandbox menu
>        item is checked.
>    - In the Sandbox column, confirm that the value for the Quick Start app
>        is Yes.
>
>    To make it easier to locate the app in Activity monitor, enter
>      the name of the Quick Start app in the Filter field.
> 3. Check that the app binary is sandboxed.
>
> `codesign -dvvv --entitlements :- executable_path`

Answer (score 8):

Finally I have chosen this workaround (because it is simple):

```
func isSandboxingEnabled() -> Bool {
    let environment = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment
    return environment["APP_SANDBOX_CONTAINER_ID"] != nil
}
```

Comment: I confirmed this to work with Xcode 11. This returns `nil` if the app is not sandboxed.